# How to simplify boolean function

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can I reduce the expression:

$(A + B' + C)(A + B' + C') $

to

$ \Rightarrow A + B' + C'$

Comment: Do you mean to $A+B'$ ?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja No, I'm following a book in which the author reduced the expression $(A + B' + C)(A + B' + C') $ to $(A + B' + C') $

Comment: try $A=FALSE$, $B=TRUE$, and $C=FALSE$ to see if it is true